# python text file in folder within the directory folder not found

Tags: python, command-prompt, subdirectory

I'm running my code in command prompt from the directory **FOLDER* "Game" within "Game" I have other **FOLDERS** to keep it neat and easier to navigate/find files, inside a folder "Text" I have a Text file named "Note8.txt" so the text file "Note8.txt" is in folder "Text" inside the directory folder "Game" but while running my code the command prompt states *error could not find "Note8" in the directory* I took "Note8.txt" out of its folder and it worked, I assumed having folders within the directory folder would automatically make them subfiles so I could still use

```
with open("Note8.txt",'r') as Note8txt:
    Note8 = read(Note8txt.read())
```

this works fine with the text file in the folder but not when the text files are inside the folder, is there a way to get this to work or dose all my files need to be inside the folder and not inside folders within the folder?[image: folders within the directory folder]

Comment: Well it's obvious isn't it, You're asking python to search for Note8.txt where the python's main file is, But when you put it inside a folder, it'll throw error for sure. SO what you gotta do is use this: with open("TEXT/Note8.txt",'r') ; assuming TEXT is the foldername you put the .txt file inside

Comment: you should specify the path of the file which you are trying to open if the file is not residing in the folder with the script file that is being run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try This**

```py
with open('TextFiles/Note8.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as file:
    print(file.read())
    file.close()
    # OR SOME OTHER CODE
```

Comment: thanks, ill give this a shot, i tried stating the location before and it came up with an error, however i stated it as the whole thing not just the folder within the folder.

Comment: thanks, i tried it and it simply worked with, with open("TextFiles/Note8.txt",'r') as Note8txt, i didnt need mode or encoding